# Какое должно быть имя сервера в Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

Tags: sql-server

C [сайта](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) скачана и установлена Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17. При первом запуске нужно выбрать сервер, нашел в советах, что надо вписать имя компьютера, но это не помогло. В командной строке команда

> osql -L

выдало "Серверы: --НЕТ--

Comment: К какому серверу Вы хотите подключиться? К локальному или в сети?

Comment: @SergeNazarenko локальному

Comment: Какая редакция SQL server у вас установлена?

Comment: @SergeNazarenko версия 17.2

Comment: На вскидку предлагаю следующие имена (в кавычках): "." или  ".\SQLExpress"

Comment: версия 17.2 - это версия студии SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @SergeNazarenko тогда не понимаю, что такое редакция и как это узнать. имена такие не подходят тоже

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65553/discussion-between-serge-nazarenko-and-nick-shepard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вы не производили установку SQL Server, а поставили только SQL Server Management Studio.

Если вам нужен SQL Server - для ознакомления предлагаю использовать версию [SQL Server Express 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express)
после установки подключение можно произвести к серверу по следующему имени: `.\SQLExpress`

Comment: Наверное, Вы правы, сейчас установлю